# codeigniter managing folder access

Tags: codeigniter, url, rewriting

I am developing a codeigniter project, which provides blog services for users. I want to give every user a folder to upload files in there.
I want to place these folders in a single folder named 'sites' and put this folder in the CI directory next to the 'application' and 'system' folders, so I have something like this:

- application
- system
- sites

  - user1_folder
  - user2_folder

one problem is that for example I want address of user1_folder/pic.jpg to be like:

```
localhost/ci/user1_folder/pic.jpg
```

instead of

```
localhost/ci/sites/user1_folder/pic.jpg
```

can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

the other problem is I want some of these sites to be locked, so I want something more like a front controller that runs by every single http request to my site to check if the requested blog is locked, and if so deny the access.

Answer (score 0):

Serve the file by a controller, like you said:

```
class File extends CI_Controller {

    public function img($user='', $img='') {

        //file exists
            //user ok
                //serve the file
    }
}
```

`site.com/file/img/user1/image.jpg`

You can rewrite this url by CI Routing

```
$route['sites/(:any)/(:any)\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)'] = 'file/img/$1/$2';
```

`site.com/sites/user1/image.jpg`

I have never do that, this is just for give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done anything like that before, but I guess there is 2 way you can do it.

The CI Controller way, like lighta have suggested. One comment is that, to do a redirect instead of reading and serving the file.

Another way is to use .htaccess